# CSS Font-face isn't working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to import a CSS font but unfortunately it's not working and I'm really unsure why.

The font in the filesystem called 'deadjim.ttf' It is placed inside my main public_html and yes it is the correct path, visiting the path downloads the file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'deadjim';
    src: url('http://url.com/deadjim.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

I've tried clearing my cache but this hasn't worked either. Apparently it's working on Safari but I have no means of checking having a windows PC

Comment: try using a relative path ... also you may need to include the `woff`formats of the font

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're calling the font like normal; @font-face doesn't apply any styles to the html, it just defines the font.

```
#Define your font
@font-face {
  font-family: 'deadjim';
  src: url('http://url.com/deadjim.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

#Will apply the font as default on the entire page
html, body{
  font-family: 'deadjim';
}
```

Comment: Yes I defined my font aswell, similar to that. I had two imported fonts and I changed them

Answer (score 0):

To be sure your font works in all browser / most platforms, you will need to do something similar to this (with all formats provided) - it's not enough to just have the .ttf-file.

Here's an example of including FontAwesome:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),
       url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), 
       url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), 
       url('fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: It seemed to be enough for my last file which was only a .ttf file. My assumption is if one ttf file works on the lastest Chrome, another one would